# Why doesn't this algorithm find the longest path in a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Ive tried to use dynamic programming to solve this question. dp[i] stores the the longest path ending at i. For every edge from x to y, i update dp[y] to the maximum between dp[y] and dp[x+1].

It works on the input output examples but fails some of the testcases while being judged. Havent been able to think of a test case in which it fails.Any help would be appreciated.

**N is number of vertices

M is number of edges

x y denotes an edge from x to y

Output should be the length of the longest path in the graph.**

- Sample Input
  N M
  x1 y1
  x2 y2
  x3 y3
  .
  .
  .
  Input 1
  4 5
  1 2
  1 3
  3 2
  2 4
  3 4
  Output 1
  3
  Input 2
  5 8
  5 3
  2 3
  2 4
  5 2
  5 1
  1 4
  4 3
  1 3
  Output 2
  3

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;

    vector<int> dp(n+1,0);
    //dp[i] denotes max length of path ending at node i
    int x,y;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>x>>y;
        dp[y]=max(dp[x]+1,dp[y]);
    }
    int ans=0;
    // for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    //  cout<<i<< " : "<<dp[i]<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
        ans=max(ans,dp[i]);
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please provide the working examples as a testcase (some input produces some output, which is check if correct). Thus, it will be much easier helping you.

Comment: What are x and y? What is computed? Your problem definition is incomplete.

Comment: I've added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that while you will indeed process each edge, you’re processing them in an order that doesn’t guarantee that you’ll actually discover the paths you want. For example, consider this DAG:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Imagine the input file has the edges in this order:

```
2 3
1 2
```

Initially, dp[1], dp[2], and dp[3] are all zero. After seeing the first line dp[2] is set to 1, and after the second dp[1] is set to 1 as well. However, these final values are incorrect because dp[2] should be 2.

The reason this fails is that the DP solution you’re looking at works only if you visit the edges in a topological ordering, in which case every time you see an edge from x to y you know you’ve already computed the length of the longest path to x before you consider updating y.

To fix this, store the edges you read in and visit the edges in a topological order of the nodes. You can find topological orderings in many ways, and I’ll leave the details to you. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Makes sense now.Thank you :)